# Update field value without edit page

Tags: entities, nodes

I need to create a button that will allow a user to update a field value on a node without accessing the edit page. I'm using access control to limit access to the node, and roles which could define which user sees the button. The field I need to update is a custom pick list.

Is there a module to do this? I can't find one. THANKS!

(More info on my specific implementation)

My site allows users to list resources for other users to book. When a user wishes to book an item, he creates a new node (Booking). The owner of the resource is also given access to this node. Here, they can comment and exchange files (attachments) to work out the details. This node has a field called "Stage", which starts as "Pending". Once the owner has confirmed the details of the booking, I want him to be able to click "Approve" on the booking node, changing the status to "Approved". When the resource has been returned, the owner should hit a "Completed" button, changing the status to "Complete". I'd also like both users to see a "Cancel" button at all times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [editablefields](https://drupal.org/project/editablefields) module.

> This module allows CCK fields to be edited on a node's display (e.g.
>   at node/123), not just on the node edit pages (e.g. node/123/edit). It
>   also works within views etc. Anywhere a 'formatter' can be selected,
>   you can select editable (or click to edit).